# Getting 492 value in DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS (download failed)

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am using [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) to download files. I am getting 492 status when download fails. However I can download the same file from any browser. The error is frequently coming for some files. After searching about the status I got that this error comes when the device does not have enough memory to store download file, but on my device I left with 2 GB of  storage. Can some one please help me to work around this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi think I found the solution. The downloading was getting failed because of special character in title. I removed the special character and then download was working fine.

Comment: I have this problem on some device, but change title and now every thing is right!

Answer (score 1):

Another possible source of the problem, which I think is more general, is that destination folder is not exists (and `DownloadManager` not always creating it for you - it is platform dependent for some reason).